# Switch lex states in flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

Could someone point me to a reference, or post a short example on how to switch lexical states in flex? A quick google search didn't give me much to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the flex buzzword for what you want to switch is ["start condition."](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html)  You can switch start conditions with [`BEGIN`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-BEGIN) and `yy_push_state()`.